# Drive Info information not showing on label in winform

Tags: c#

My code is supposed to show The Drive Name and other information when I select the Drive (ex. 'C:' )
I have this code here to show the Drive info on the winform but somehow it wont show up on my winform, just blank?

```
        string lblnametype = Drive_Info.Name;
        string lblvolumetype = Drive_Info.VolumeLabel;
        string lblRoot = Convert.ToString(Drive_Info.RootDirectory);
```

Comment: Have you assigned variable into label's "Text" property?

Comment: All you're doing is assigning to strings... your app is not going to magically display every string you create on the screen. What controls are you trying to display the data on?

Comment: Yeah I know. Silly me i totally forgot about it , too much code going on the head haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually assign them to your controls' `Text` properties...

For example:

```
lblnametype.Text = Drive_Info.Name;
```

`lblnametype` in the above example must be an actual control on your page...

Comment: OHHH. Silly me, No Wonder!! Took me 2 hours to figure this out and this was the problem all along. Too much code going on my head haha

Comment: @CaptainYang Happens to the best of us! Don't forget to mark as answer if it helped :)